# HTML display-inline

Tags: html, css

i am trying to write this picture:

[image: this picture].

There are actually 3 elements - img, h3 & paragraph... I want to have two boxes - in the first box will be img vertically aligned in the middle and second box contains H3 (align:left) and under H3 there is a paragraph.

My code is as follows (I can only use inline CSS):

```
 <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
<div style="border:1px solid grey;">
<div name="first_box" style="float:left;">
  <img style="margin-top:30px;" src="https://rsm.cz/wp-content/uploads/virtu.png" alt="try" />
</div>
<div name="second_box" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:1px 2px 1px 2px;">
 <h3 style="text-align:left;">Virtualizace</h3>
<p>Virtualizace infrastruktury umožňuje snížení nákladů na podporu IT systémů, zhodnocení investic do vybavení IT, zefektivnění práce zaměstnanců a procesů.</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"I can not use CSS now"_? Your code snippet contains inline CSS...

Comment: He probably means "I can only use inline CSS".

Comment: "display:inline" is CSS, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Keep both boxes as a "display:inline-block" with a vertical-align as middle.
Quickly mocked this up. Let me know if it works.

```
<div style="width:515px">
  <div style="width:100px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-right:10px;">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  </div>
  <div style="width:400px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
    <h3>Title here</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab neque fuga eligendi, obcaecati ad unde debitis, suscipit sed illum soluta blanditiis aspernatur saepe voluptatum eum quod quae laborum a temporibus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
<div style="border:1px solid grey;">
<p>
<img src="https://rsm.cz/wp-content/uploads/virtu.png" alt="try" style="float:left;" "margin-top:30px>
<h3>Virtualizace</h3>
<p>Virtualizaceinfrastruktury umožňuje snížení nákladů na podporu IT systémů, zhodnocení investic do vybavení IT, zefektivnění práce zaměstnanců a procesů.</p>
</div>  
</p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float
The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: I edited the float concept to my answer to explain how it works